# python ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'gplearn'

Tags: python, command-line, module, pycharm

I created a project in Pycharm including a `gp.py`, copied the project folder to another machine and tried to run the gp.py script from command line using `python gp.py`. However I got a error 
`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "gp.py", line 2, in <module>
    from gplearn.genetic import SymbolicRegressor
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'gplearn'`

The thing is I could see this `gplearn` library I used in the project folder, like below. The screen shot is not from Pycharm but the folder I copied to another computer. I tried to place the `gp.py`inside and outside venv folder but neither worked. Could you please help to point out what the problem is ? Many thanks

[image]

Comment: just write down #import gplearn in your .py file

Comment: I need to use this gplearn library

Comment: then run the - pip install gplearn  in your project folder or environment file

Comment: I could see this gplearn library in the folder I copied to the new machine tho. Do I need to install it? How can I create a project--> copy to new machine and the user could just run the .py file without installing? –

Comment: without installing user cant run .py file it will also find in installed package from machine

Comment: doesn't seem to be like this. That's the error I got from just running gp.py file..

Answer (score 1):

gplearn package is not installed in the new machine.

Go to cmd prompt/terminal in pycharm and execute below line:

```
pip install gplearn
```

Comment: but I could see this gplearn library in the folder in the new machine. do I need to install it? How can I create a project--> copy to new machine and the user could just run the .py file without installing?

Comment: You will need to install the packages in the new machine. You can create a requirements.txt file in the existing machine for the project, and when you copy the project to new machine, you can just run pip install requirements.txt and all the dependencies will be installed.

Answer (score 1):

Sound like you are seeking for a method to deploy your script to end user, in this case maybe you can give Pyinstaller a try.

Comment: So if I want to use some 3rd party libraries, and have another user to be able to just run that .py file to execute that program, I need to use pyinstaller to package it? I can’t just copy the whole project folder including the libraries to another machine?

Comment: I think you can wrap it with a batch/script file to 1) Activate the venv or setup the path and env variable 2) Run script